# Double rendering with EJS in node.js

Tags: node.js, templates, render, ejs

I wonder if it's possible to do a double rendering with ejs with different tags.

For example I've got this ejs template

```
<@= test @>

<% for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++) { %>
    <li>
        <%= people[i].name %>
    </li>
<%
    }
%>
```

In node.js I'm rendering either with the default tags (<%) or with some defined tags (<@) like this

```
var people = [{"name":"Martin"}, {"name":"Jean"}];

 exports.test = function(req, res) {
    res.render('template', {
        open:'<@',close:'@>',
        people : people,
        test : "Hello world"
    })
}
```

This code will render

```
Hello world <% for(var i=0; i
<%= people[i].name %>
<% } %>
```

And this one

```
var people = [{"name":"Martin"}, {"name":"Jean"}];

 exports.test = function(req, res) {
    res.render('template', {
        people : people,
        test : "Hello world"
    })
}
```

will render

```
<@= test @>
Martin
Jean
```

And I'd like to find a way to double render it like this:

```
Hello world
Martin
Jean
```

Thanks

**SOLUTION thanks to bnuhero**

```
 exports.test = function(req, res) {
 var people = [{"name":"Martin"}, {"name":"Jean"}];
     res.render( 'test',
          {open:'<@', close:'@>', test : "Hello world"},
          function(err, html) {
            if (err) {
            console.log(err);
              res.send(500, err);
            } else {
              res.send(require('ejs').render(html, {people: people}))
            }
         });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, call `res.render()` by providing a callback function. Both the possible error and the rendered string are passed to this callback function. `res.render()` won't perform automated response to the client side.

Second, apply `require('ejs').render()` to the rendered string in the callback function.

Finally, send the result to the client side.

```
exports.test = function(req, res) {
  var people = [{"name":"Martin"}, {"name":"Jean"}];
  res.render( 'template',
              {open:'<@', close:'@>', test : "Hello world"},
              function(err, html) {
                if (err) {
                  res.send(500, err);
                } else {
                  res.send(require('ejs').render(html, {people: people}));
                };
             });
};
```

Comment: Thank you ! Worked perfectly. I edited your code though there was a small typo and also for some reason ejs doesn't like the ";" at the end of the last res.

Comment: I can't edit if it's less than 6 characters so I've edited my question with the answer. Thanks again